# WCF - Java web service interop - Signed outgoing message not accepted

Tags: wcf, ws-security, interop

I try to sign a message using a certificate and a private key to call a java (JBoss) web service, but the server refuses to accept my signed message. It only echoes back the same message that I've sent.

I have successfully signed the outgoing message using the certificate, and the structure of the message look alright when I compare it to an exampel message supplied by the web service creator.

I use a custom binding declared as shown below

```
<binding name="FSACustomServiceBinding"
             closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:01:00">
      <textMessageEncoding
        messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <security
        authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
        requireDerivedKeys="false"
        keyEntropyMode="ClientEntropy"
        includeTimestamp="false"
        securityHeaderLayout="Lax"
        messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
        messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
        <secureConversationBootstrap />
      </security>
      <httpTransport/>
    </binding>
```

and the resulting message looks like this

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-0794e8c9-f354-42de-acf2-3d2caf80ff9c-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">[BINARYSECURITYTOKEN]</o:BinarySecurityToken>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
 <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
 <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
 <Reference URI="#_1">
 <Transforms>
  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
 </Transforms>
 <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>[DIGESTVALUE]</DigestValue>
 </Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>[SIGNATUREVALUE]</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
 <o:SecurityTokenReference><o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-0794e8c9-f354-42de-acf2-3d2caf80ff9c-2"/></o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature></o:Security></s:Header>
<s:Body u:Id="_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><list xmlns="http://etis.ford.com/services/fsa/1.0"><String_1 xmlns="">[VINNUMBER]</String_1></list></s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

An exampel message that works with the web service:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://etis.ford.com/services/fsa/1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<env:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" env:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="token-26-1284446233382-10880960">[BINARYSECURITYTOKEN]</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
 <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
 <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
 <ds:Reference URI="#element-25-1284446233382-9656454">
 <ds:Transforms>
  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
 </ds:Transforms>
 <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
 <ds:DigestValue>[DIGESTVALUE]</ds:DigestValue>
 </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>[SIGNATUREVALUE]</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
 <wsse:SecurityTokenReference><wsse:Reference URI="#token-26-1284446233382-10880960"     ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature></wsse:Security></env:Header>
<env:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="element-25-1284446233382-9656454"><ns0:list><String_1>[VINNUMBER]</String_1></ns0:list></env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I've run out of ideas, and the web service creator doesn't supply any information what so ever as to why my message isn't accepted.

Does anyone have an idea?

Regards,
Simon

Comment: Hey Simon, did you get anywhere on this?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you are using a self signed certificate that the Jboss server does not trust.